# Como Fazer uma Mascara para validação de campo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer uma mascar para um campo onde o usurário não érre esse padrão a baixo

exemplo
'0.50','0.60','0.70'

os valores decimais sempre dentro de aspas e separados por virgula

se digitado errado mostrar mensagem

Comment: Conseguiu  rapaz ?

Comment: Veja se minha resposta é o que você necessita.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin), e utilizar [Expressões Regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) para verificar o valor do campo. Veja o exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var campo = $('.campo');
 var alert = $('.erro');
 var mascara = "'0.00'";
 var fnc = function(v) {
  // Se o texto do campo tiver o mesmo tamanho
  // que a variável mascara, incrementa: ,'0.00' e faz o retorno,
  // caso contrário retorna o valor atual da variável mascara
  return (v.length === mascara.length) ? mascara += ",'0.00'" : mascara;
 };
 var options = {
  onKeyPress: function(v, e, f, o) {
      console.log(v);
      const reg = /('\d{1}\.\d{2}',?)|(\d+)|(\')/g;
      let result = true;
      var test = v.match(reg);
      if (test) {
          test.forEach(r => {
              if (/('\d{1}\.\d{2}',?)/.test(r) === false) {
                  result = false;
              }
          });
      }
      // Verifica se o valor da variável 'result' é falso
      // caso for exibi a mensagem, caso contrário oculta.
      (result === false) ? alert.show(): alert.hide();
      campo.mask(fnc(v), o);
  }
 };
 campo.mask(mascara, options);
});
```

```css
.test {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px;
}
.erro {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

div.erro {
    background: #ff7675;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.13/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="campo" />
<div class="erro">Dados invalidos</div>
```

#### Explicando:

- **'**
  Permite aspas simples
- **\d{1}**
  Permite somente um digito após a aspas.
- **.**
  Permite um ponto.
- **\d{2}**
  Permite somente dois dígitos após o ponto.
- **,?**
  Permite uma virgula opcional após a aspas.
- **|(\d+)|(\')**
  Recupera o restante do valor que o usuário digitou, para verificar esta preenchido corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isto pode te ajudar:

Javascript:

```
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var logger = document.getElementById("logger");
  var $array = ["'0.50'","'0.60'","'0.70'"];
  var i;

  function validar(){

    var $descartavel = input.value;

    for (i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
      if($descartavel.indexOf($array[i]) != -1){ 
        logger.innerHTML = "";
      }else{
        if(i == 10){
          i = 0;
        }
        logger.innerHTML = "Valores estão inválidos! Corrija-os por favor!";
      }
     }
  }
```

HTML:

```
     <input type="text" id="input" onkeyup="validar()"/><br/><br />

      <div id="logger" style="background:#f44336;color:#fff;">
```

Comment: Parceiro não rodou aqui.  outra coisa esses valores var $array = ["'0.50'","'0.60'","'0.70'"]; não são para comparar é so pra mostrar que qualquer outra valor vai ter que ficar dentro de  aspas e separado por virgula

Comment: Você precisa criar seu próprio código de validação, com expressões regulares, ou algo do tipo.. Eu dei apenas uma ideia do que pode fazer..